# How to execute MySQL query through PHP in the proper way?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have written the query below but there are no errors and no records are updated.

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO members (username, password, email)
                   VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')");
```

Comment: But is anything INSERTed?

Comment: no empty table showing

Comment: You will need to show the whole script for anyone to be able to help. Also tell us what you know; are you certainly connected to DB, are the variables shown in the query populated?..

Comment: your question is very short on information and code. We have no way of knowing which MySQL API you're using to connect and if you even successfully connected. If your POST arrays contains values etc. the list goes on. Check for errors is all I can suggest to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using PDO (php Data Object)

```
     $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=account','root','password');
    // insert the new member
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO member (username, password, firstname, joinDate)
    VALUES (:username, :password, :firstname, NOW())';
    $stmt = $db_conn->prepare($sql);

// perform query
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':name' => 'okanlawonE12',
    ':password' => 'okanlawonEmmanuel',
    ':firstname' => 'emmanuel')
    );
// echo last inserted row
    echo "New Member has been added: " . $db_conn->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good, check your variables (Username, Password and Email) maybe they are empty, try using `echo "Username: " . $username . " ,Password: " . $password " ,Email : " . $email;` to check them. This code bellow is from one of my projects, I modified the variables so it matches your variables.

```
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, password, email) 
            VALUES (':username', ':password', ':email')"); 

            $stmt->execute(array(
                 "username" => $username,
                 "password" => $password,
                 "email" => $email)
            );
```

"Prepared statements are used to sanitize your input, and to do that you can use :foo without any single quotes within the SQL to bind variables, and then in the execute() function you pass in an array of the variables you defined in the SQL statement." @Novocaine (https://stackoverflow.com/users/871150/novocaine).